How to i delete mutiple elements of json file on python
I am trying to delete mutiple information of a json file but I dont know what to do in python to resolve the problem
I tried add() it doesnt work and pop() and i can't make it to work either so what other option is their that I can try

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Wondering, if you tried using "del" keyword.

Load the json data into a dictionary "data".
Delete the key-value pairs for keys you want to delete.
Save the new dictionary data into a new json file.

Sample code -
import json

with open('data_file.json', 'r') as file:
   data = json.load(file)

keys_to_delete = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']
for k in keys_to_delete:
   if k in data:
      del data[k]

with open('new_data.json', 'w') as file:
   json.dump(data, file)


It's not really helpful to answer such unclear questions. Right now, it's not even clear if the data in the JSON file results in dictionary, how deep it is nested, etc.
